# Gradient, Hessian, and minimum of a vector function?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vector-analysis, jacobian, hessian-matrix

Given the function $f(\vec{x})=(\frac{1}{2})\vec{x}^TP^TP\vec{x}+q^T\vec{x}+r$, where $\vec{x}$ and $q \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n x n}$ is full rank and $r \in \mathbb{R}$, I am trying to find the gradient, Hessian, and what the minimum of this function is.

For the sake of simplicity, I am going to say $n=2$ and define the following as:

$\vec{x}= \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}$

$ P = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12}\\
p_{21} & p_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$

$\vec{q}= \begin{bmatrix}
q_1\\
q_2
\end{bmatrix}$

This is what I computed for the gradient:

$\frac{\partial f(\vec{x})}{\partial x_1} = x_1p^2_{11} + x_1p^2_{21} + x_2p_{11}p_{12} + x_2p_{21}p_{22} + q_1$

$\frac{\partial f(\vec{x})}{\partial x_2} = x_1p_{11}p_{12} + x_1p_{21}p_{22} + x_2p^2_{12} + x_2p^2_{22} + q_2$

For the Hessian, I got the following: $\begin{bmatrix}
p^2_{11} + p^2_{21} & p_{11}p_{12} + p_{21}p_{22}\\
p_{11}p_{12} + p_{21}p_{22} & p^2_{11} + p^2_{21}
\end{bmatrix}$

Are my computations of the gradient and Hessian correct? From here, how do I find the minimum of this function?

Answer (score 1):

What is is interesting is at least sufficient condition to have that extremum:

**If $a$ is a critical point**

$f$ has a strict minimum in $a$ if $H(f)(a)$ is defined positive (resp. defined negative for a maximum)

Recalling that defined positive is that

$$  \forall x \in R^2, x \neq \vec{0,  }\, x^tH(f)(a)x>0 $$

**Begin by determining the critical point (annulation of gradient is necessary)**